# How can I add the matching numbers from two arrays to an empty third array using for and if statements?

Tags: java

How can I add the matching numbers from the two arrays, called Table and Table2, to an empty third array (Table3) using for- and if-statments, and then print the Table3 content?

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        int[] Table = new int[5];

        Table[0] = 35;
        Table[1] = 26;
        Table[2] = 70;
        Table[3] = 130;
        Table[4] = 10;

        int[] Table2 = new int[5];

        Table2[0] = 35;
        Table2[1] = 1;
        Table2[2] = 70;
        Table2[3] = 5;
        Table2[4] = 10;
        

        int[] Table3 = new int[5];

        for(int i=0; i<Table.length; i++){
      
           if (Table2[i] == Table[i]){
              Table3[i] = Table2[i];
           } else if (Table[i] < Table2[i] || Table[i] > Table2[i]){
              System.out.println("No matching numbers");
           }
        }
        
    System.out.println(Table3);
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the expected output? It would clear up the question and help us help you

Comment: First thing I would do is fix the typo `Tauble[i]` in the if clause.

Comment: @Mureinik So matching numbers from Table and Table2 should be added to the Table3. The expected output should show numbers 35 70 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a second variable in the for-loop that keeps track of postion in new 'Table'. Like this:

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] Table = new int[5];

        Table[0] = 35;
        Table[1] = 26;
        Table[2] = 70;
        Table[3] = 130;
        Table[4] = 10;

        int[] Table2 = new int[5];

        Table2[0] = 35;
        Table2[1] = 1;
        Table2[2] = 70;
        Table2[3] = 5;
        Table2[4] = 10;

        int[] Table3 = new int[5];

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < Table.length; i++) {

            if (Table2[i] == Table[i]) {
                Table3[j++] = Table2[i];
            } else if (Table[i] < Table2[i] || Table[i] > Table2[i]) {
                System.out.println("No matching numbers");
            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i< Table3.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Table3[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem you are left with now is that you will end up with an array that is filled as follows: 35 70 10 0 0. But I will leave it up to you to figure out how to get rid of those zeros.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] Table = new int[5];

    Table[0] = 35;
    Table[1] = 26;
    Table[2] = 70;
    Table[3] = 130;
    Table[4] = 10;

    int[] Table2 = new int[5];

    Table2[0] = 35;
    Table2[1] = 1;
    Table2[2] = 70;
    Table2[3] = 5;
    Table2[4] = 10;


    int[] Table3 = new int[5];
    int table3Counter = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<Table.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j< Table2.length;j++){
            if(Table[i]==Table2[j]){
                Table3[table3Counter]=Table[i];
                table3Counter++;
            }
        }

    }
    for(int i=0; i<Table3.length; i++){
        System.out.println(Table3[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be if you could declare a method and stimulate the logic there
The **findCommon** method finds common numbers in two arrays and returns a new `int []` array.
Basically you need `2 for loops` to iterate through 2 `int [] arrays`
and if `if(arr1[i] == arr2[j])` is true it means array1 has an element that array2 has it too. so then we increase a `count++` so then we know the size of our array that we are going to return. Next we go with the same logic but this time we add element on the `int[] arrayForReturn` with  `arrayForReturn[arrayIndex++] = arr1[i];`

```
public class ArrayTest{


    public static void main(String[] args) {


    int[] Table = new int[5];

    Table[0] = 35;
    Table[1] = 26;
    Table[2] = 70;
    Table[3] = 130;
    Table[4] = 10;

    int[] Table2 = new int[5];

    Table2[0] = 35;
    Table2[1] = 1;
    Table2[2] = 70;
    Table2[3] = 5;
    Table2[4] = 10;

    int [] common = findCommon(Table,Table2);

        for (int i: common
             ) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

}

    private static int [] findCommon(int[] arr1, int[] arr2){
        int count = 0;
        int arrayIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++){
                if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]){
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        int[] arrayForReturn = new int[count];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++){
                if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]){
                    arrayForReturn[arrayIndex++] = arr1[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return arrayForReturn;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need another `for loop`. Outer for loop pick an element from Table and inner for loop checks is there any matching.
2. Outside declare `k` variable, this will keep track of the current index of Table3.

```
int k = 0;
for(int i= 0 ; i < Table.length; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<Table.length; j++)
    {
         if (Table2[j] == Table[i])
         {
             Table3[k++] = Table2[j];
         } else {
             System.out.println("No matching numbers");
         }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] table1 = new int[5];

        table1[0] = 35;
        table1[1] = 26;
        table1[2] = 70;
        table1[3] = 130;
        table1[4] = 10;

        int[] table2 = new int[5];

        table2[0] = 35;
        table2[1] = 1;
        table2[2] = 70;
        table2[3] = 5;
        table2[4] = 10;

        List<Integer> table3 = new ArrayList<>();

        int minLength = Math.min(table1.length, table2.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
            if (table1[i] == table2[i]) {
                table3.add(table1[i]);
            }
        }

        int[] output;
        if (table3.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No matching numbers");
        } else {
            output = table3.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use List to accumulate result and then create array:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] Table = new int[5];

    Table[0] = 35;
    Table[1] = 26;
    Table[2] = 70;
    Table[3] = 130;
    Table[4] = 10;

    int[] Table2 = new int[5];

    Table2[0] = 35;
    Table2[1] = 1;
    Table2[2] = 70;
    Table2[3] = 5;
    Table2[4] = 10;

    List<Integer> List3 = new ArrayList();
  
    for (int i = 0; i < Table.length; i++) {
        if (Table2[i] == Table[i]) {
            List3.add(Table2[i]);
            System.out.println("Matched: "+Table2[i]);
        } else if (Table[i] < Table2[i] || Table[i] > Table2[i])
            System.out.println("No matching numbers");
    }

    int[] Table3 = new int[List3.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < List3.size(); i++)
        Table3[i] = List3.get(i);

    for (int i = 0; i < Table3.length; i++)
        System.out.println(Table3[i]);
  }
}
```